# Hide : in title when no angular query has been made

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently I am using:

`<title ng-bind-template="FuturePhones: {{query}}">FuturePhones</title>`

But this means that when the page is loaded the title will be:

> FuturePhones:

If i query my controller for "iPhone" i get the title:

> FuturePhones:  iPhone

How do I in the simplest way hide the **:** until a query has been completed?

```
  <title ng-bind-template="FuturePhones {{query ? ':'+query : ''}}">FuturePhones</title>
```

Does not work, it destroys the query...
The query comes from:

```
<b>Search:</b><input ng-model="query" placeholder="Find...">
```

Answer (score 0):

With simple ternary operator:

```html
<title ng-bind-template="FuturePhones{{query ? ': ' + query : ''}}">FuturePhones</title>
```

Comment: really? can you use {{}} inside ng-bind?

Comment: If your model "gets destroyed" by the unrelated conditional than there's something horribly wrong with your setup. [Working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kpPNf0BKpUgsqgRX9SWC?p=preview).